# Azure Bicep deploy - Cannot find path 'C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\<guid>\<template>.json

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

Trying to deploy to Azure using a bicep template that I'm calling from PowerShell within VSCode as follows:

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name Deployment1 -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -TemplateFile $templateFile -TemplateParameterFile $parameterFile
```

This has been working fine but when I added the following lines (to create a blob container)

```
resource callDataContainer 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers@2021-04-01' = {
name: '${storageAccountName}/default/call-data'
}
```

It fails with:

```
Cannot find path 'C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\<guid>\<template>.json
```

I've proved that the bicep template is ok with:

```
az bicep build --file .\<template>.bicep
```

and this compiles to a json arm template ok

Since the "Cannot find path" error message is a little unhelpful any ideas what else I can do to figure out the cause?

Comment: are you deploying the bicep file directly or the generated arm ? Can you confirm that it is working if you remove the container creation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hit this problem again (v0.4.613 of the Bicep CLI). This time it was because I'd changed the name used for an output param of a called module. I found that even though the bicep file compiled ok, when I checked the created json it still had the old name - even after deleting and re-creating the json file.

The error message when calling the deployment from the PowerShell command "New-AzResourceGroupDeployment" was not helpful but when using the Azure CLI equivalent "az deployment group create" this did point me at the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Juts came back to this after the weekend and it worked fine